# Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 Sever Behaviours disappearing

Tags: php, sql, adobe, dreamweaver

in Dreamweaver CS6, my server behaviours will turn from whatever one it is, whether it be "Log In User", or "Insert Record" to "Dynamic Attribute (form.action (?php echo.......", aka the code for the Log In User or Insert Record.

I.E. it goes from this:

[image: s]

To this:

[image: this]

The error occurs after i save the template and it updates the pages.

Comment: This isn't really a coding issue, rather software behaviour. In my experience, Dreamweaver templates are troublesome. My advice: don't use them. Learn a more efficient way of coding by using included scripts/html formatting. I use Dreamweaver an en editor, but do not use the built in `server behaviours`.

Comment: It may be daunting at first, but it's worth it in the long run. If you do the coding by hand, then you'll understand how it all works. Start off with some tutorials on `including` files: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp